# Creating an O(n) algorithm for an array of integers

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, algorithm, homework

To avoid plagiarism in my university, I am going to modify the problem.

Henry likes to jump from building to building. The heights of each building are given as a list of H numbers. We also number their indices 0,1,…,n−1 from left to right. I want to find out the number of all the buildings that Henry can jump to with these conditions:

Henry can jump from building x to another building y if:

- The building y is not taller than building x
- None of the buildings in between building x and building y are taller than either building x or building y.

For example, if a building x has a height 10, and a building y has a height of 5, and there's a building that has a height of 7 between them, then Henry cannot jump to building y because the building's height in between them is greater than y.

For each building, how many buildings can Henry jump to?
I want it to return as a list.

Here are more examples:

> [10, 300, 200] == [0, 2, 0]
>
> Henry cannot jump from building 0 to 1
> because 300 > 10. Henry also cannot jump
> from building 0 to building 2 as building 2
> is greater than building 0 and the building
> in between them is greater than both of them.
> Henry can jump from building 1 to building 0
> and building 2 because building 2 is greater
> than both of them. Jumping from building 2 to
> building 1 is not possible as it has a greater
> height than building 1 and we cannot jump from
> building 2 to building 0 because the building
> in between them (building 1) has a height
> greater than both of them even though building 2 is greater than building 0.
>
> [10000, 1004, 1200] == [2, 0, 1]
> [1020, 1020, 1020, 220, 520, 602, 320] == [2, 2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0]

I've created an O(n^3) solution using two for loops for this solution but it seems highly inefficient. I want to see if there is an O(n log n) solution or an O(n) solution for this one. I am kind of a newbie to programming so something simple could help.

Here is my code:

```py
def valid_jumps(N: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    validated: list[int] = []
    for i in range(len(N)):
        valid = 0
        for j in range(i+1, len(N)):
            if N[i] >= N[j]:
                valid += 1
                if max(N[i+1:j], default=0) > N[i]:
                    valid -= 1
                elif max(N[i+1:j], default=0) > N[j]:
                    valid -= 1
            else:
                break

        for k in range(i-1, -1, -1):
            if N[i] >= N[k]:
                valid += 1
                if max(N[k+1:i], default=0) > N[i]:
                    valid -= 1
                elif max(N[k+1:i], default=0) > N[k]:
                    valid -= 1
            else:
                break
        validated.append(valid)
    return validated
```

Another edit: Tried to made my post clearer

Comment: Hi I've edited my post with my code. This is also not for a programming competition but was an activity given a month ago given to us by our professor in our university. It was exceeding the time limit and I can't make it more efficient. I want to learn to make my code more efficient as we have an upcoming coding exam which are algorithmic in nature according to him.

Comment: First, critically, the description is inaccurate because this is not an O(n^2) algorithm. `for; for; max` means O(n^3).

Comment: Oops, i'm fairly new to big O notation so sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: It's OK. Essentially, the `max()` implies a third hidden `for` loop contained in the Python runtime's own code.

Comment: I see. Thanks! Do you have any idea how to make this more efficient though? O(n³) seems bad.

Comment: People are more likely to answer this if you better clarify the problem.  Please take an example input and explain in English what it needs to do to product an output.  Also, in your examples, it's not clear what is input and what is output.

Comment: Hi! I made the post clearer if it helps.

Comment: Probably an efficient algorithm iterates left to right, identifying possible jumps to the right. Next it iterates right to left, identifying possible jumps to the left. That would be O(n).

Comment: You say **For example, if a building x has a height 10, and a building y has a height of 5, and there's a building that has a height of 7 between them, then Henry cannot jump to building y because the building's height in between them is greater than y.** If those are the rules so be it. But according to your rules a person can jump from a height of 10 to a height of 7 and then again from a height of 7 to a height of 5. So it makes no sense to me to say one cannot go 10 -> 7 -> 5. Remember, we are not trying to jump a height of 5 to a height of 7. Direction should matter.

Answer (score 5):

## lint

```
def valid_jumps(N: ...
```

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you spell the parameter name in this way: `n`

The problem statement suggested referring to it as `h`.

## docstring

It's unclear, from reading the code,
how to interpret the input and output vectors.
(I *do* thank you for the helpful type annotations!)
Please write an English sentence describing what
this function does, and then describe what
the input and output values mean.
Cite the original problem statement, perhaps via an URL,
if that makes it easier to write the docstring.

## too long

This function is a mere two dozen lines of source code,
and is easily viewed in a single window with no scrolling,
so ordinarily we might say that it is Fine as-is.

But it is dense.
It is clear the `j` loop is trying to accomplish
a specific goal, and so is the `k` loop,
yet those goals are unnamed.
Would you please Extract Helper, twice, and
take the opportunity to informatively name those helper functions.
Consider giving one or both of them a docstring.
Maybe we need just a single helper, which accepts a `direction`
parameter of ±1 ?

The meaning of `valid` is unclear.
It would benefit from a # comment,
as typically such a name would correspond to a boolean.
Consider renaming to `valid_count` or `num_valid_jumps`.
Part of the trouble here is that `valid` is an adjective,
yet the problem statement focuses on a certain noun: "jumps".

## inner loops

It's unclear why we're asking python's max()
to examine lots of heights which turn out to be irrelevant,
when bailing out early (`for` .. `break`, or `while`)
will save us the work.

Write an appropriate helper so you can express
the leftward + rightward jumps problem in this way:

```
        valid = _jumps(N, i, -1) + _jumps(N, i, 1)
```

## unit tests

Take a moment to fit the current implementation into a
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).
Now you can easily re-run the tests, verifying Green bar,
after each code edit.

Armed with a working cubic implementation,
you're in a great position to define some similarly named
quadratic implementation, and to verify it computes
the identical jump results.
Unit tests can make refactors happen quickly.

## memoize

Suppose building `i` is a local maximum,
from which Henry can gaze "downhill" rightward for a
long distance, all the way to some taller building `j`.
We should be able to exploit that fact when finding
valid rightward jumps for `i+1`, `i+2`, ..., `j-1`.

From `i` we can make `j-i-1` jumps.
And then we decrement that quantity for each position
until we get to `j`.
This suggests that the scalar `for i ...: valid = left + right`
which I proposed above is not a terrific fit for this problem.
Prefer to allocate `left = [0] * len(N)`,
and similarly for `right`.
Now we can greedily fill in monotonic stretches.
At the end we essentially `return left + right`.
That's valid vector notation for
[numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html),
but for `list[int]` you'll need to write a loop,
perhaps as a list comprehension involving
[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: I don't think PEP-8 is correct, here. `n` is usually used for a single `int`, whereas `N` suggests a list of `int` in mathematics. You'd usually write something like `ns` – or, I suppose, `h`.

Comment: PEP-8 is by definition correct; it is not held accountable to e.g. the [AMS](https://www.ams.org). However yes, I take your point. I understand the centuries long tradition and routinely bite my tongue on code reviews which involve an explicit citation to mathematical material which employs such notation. In this particular case the python code is less helpful than it could be. A plural container name would help. I reject `nums` as vague. I considered proposing `heights` but bit my tongue so as not to muddy the waters.

Comment: PEP-8 is only correct because it contains a passage: “However, know when to be inconsistent – sometimes style guide recommendations just aren’t applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best. And don’t hesitate to ask!” That said: I see no reason not to spend a few paragraphs explaining your thoughts on naming conventions, even if you end up giving five or six different suggestions. The two sentences you've got right now don't explain anything, so aren't that helpful (except to people who don't need advice).

Comment: I am happy to explain myself. Many remarks arise when reading code, related to "why is this hard to understand? how could the author have aided my rapid comprehension?" I write down a subset of them, with the goals of (1.) improving the code artifact in front of us prior to merging it down to `main`, and (2.) improving code the author shall write in future, that is, I'm trying to teach. You have to "pick your battles", since no codebase will ever be perfect, and I try to meet each author where they are. Here, I believed the author hadn't read PEP-8, and should.

Answer (score 4):

The code layout is good.

It is clear from the code that the function accepts a list of integers and returns a list of integers.

However, you should add a docstring describing more details about the returned list.  You could add details for the following:

- It returns a list of the same length as the input list (if that is the case)
- It appears to return a `valid` indication for each item in the input list.  I think of "valid" as being a boolean (1 or 0).  What does 2 mean?  What does 5 mean?

Essentially, it would be better to more precisely define what you mean by "valid".

### [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Since your function does not modify the input list `N`, its length remains the same.  However, your code calls `len(N)` multiple times:

```
for i in range(len(N)):
    valid = 0
    for j in range(i+1, len(N)):
```

Instead, you can set the length to a variable at the top of the function:

```
nums = len(N)
for i in range(nums):
    valid = 0
    for j in range(i+1, nums):
```

Similarly for the calls to `max`:

```
            if max(N[i+1:j], default=0) > N[i]:
                valid -= 1
            elif max(N[i+1:j], default=0) > N[j]:
```

This is simpler:

```
            max_num = max(N[i+1:j], default=0)
            if  max_num > N[i]:
                valid -= 1
            elif max_num > N[j]:
```

### Input checking

If the input to your function is known to be good, in other words, if you validate the input before passing it to the function, then ignore the following.  Otherwise, consider checking the input in the function.  For example, if the input contains a negative value, the output is not what I would expect.  Obviously, there is no such thing as a negative height, but you might want to report it to the user.  Checking would take some time to do, but it would only be done once for each item in the list.

Comment: Hello, I made my post clearer! I modified the problem. Pleade let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved in O(n) by maintaining a monotonic stack of heights of previous buildings. For each new building, remove all elements from the stack with height not greater than the current element. Any buildings with height less than the current building are reachable from the current building, but not from any other buildings as the current building blocks it. We handle elements with the same height by also keeping track of the frequency of buildings with equal height in the stack.

```py
def valid_jumps(heights: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    ans = [0] * len(heights)
    def solve(elems):
        stk = []
        for i, height in elems:
            tot = same = 0
            while stk and stk[-1][0] <= height:
                curr, freq = stk.pop()
                if curr == height: same += freq
                tot += freq
            ans[i] += tot
            stk.append((height, same + 1))
    solve(enumerate(heights))
    solve(reversed(list(enumerate(heights))))
    return ans
```

Comment: I'm unclear on how this is O(n). Surely the `for`/`while` exceeds O(n).

Comment: @Reinderien Every element enters and leaves the stack at most once, hence the sum of the number of iterations of the inner while loop is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

My approach, n log n:

```
def valid_jumps_1(N: list[int]) -> list[int]:
valid: list[int] = [0] * len(N)
for i in range(len(N)):
    j = i - 1;
    while j >= 0 and N[i] > N[j]:
        valid[i] += 1
        j -= 1
    j = i + 1
    while j < len(N) and N[i] > N[j]:
        valid[i] += 1
        j += 1
return valid
```

Appears to be n^2 but if you notice the two loops break condition, it evaluates if it has reached one value greater from one side or another.
This avoid again looping the entire array and in the best case it breaks the first iteration on the two loops!! for each position in the array.

-You original code benchmark with 35000 random integers (on a laptop 10th gen i5 10210U 4.2GHz):
real    1m4,184s
user    1m3,965s
sys 0m0,010s

- n log n code benchmark with 1000000 random integers (again same pc):
  real    0m3,312s
  user    0m3,148s
  sys 0m0,085s

My test bench code :

```
import random
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,1000000):
    n = random.randint(1,1000000)
    randomlist.append(n)

print(randomlist)
#print(valid_jumps(randomlist))
print(valid_jumps_1(randomlist))
```

Comment: I think this is still O(n^2) in the worst case, as if the buildings all have the same height your loops will never break before going through each building.

Comment: Actually, your solution as written may be incorrect for buildings with the same height. You need to use `>=` rather than `>` to compare heights

Comment: You need to indent the code in the 1st code block properly.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! it appears you have a registered for an account twice (as evidenced by the suggested edit), and those two can be merged. You can use the [contact SE page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact) near the end of the page and request the accounts be merged.